# How can i limit and expand the content of UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am facing a problem regarding UITextView content in which I am getting data from the server and if the content is large then I should display limited content and then by the use of a "Load More" titled button I can load additional content from the server.

How can I do this?

Comment: Strange upvote for a question that doesn't present a programming problem.

Comment: @Hiren : Have you find any answer relative? If yes, then can you please upvote and accept the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this at server side. If data is big set a property of data true. On client side use this property for more button.

Answer (score 0):

You fetch the total content, check its length. If It would be greater than the limited content then show the title button, and on click of button re-frame the textView and show the total content.
Here I assume 200 characters can be contained in the textview having height 100

Example

```
UITextView *txtVw = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:txtVw];


NSString *strContent = @"content from server";
if (strContent.length > 200) {
    NSLog(@"Write your code to show the MORE title button");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Show the text");
}
```

Comment: Its not a solution. He wants to show a small part of content and want to load full content on request. Your solution is not correct.

Comment: @Rashad, The same we can do on request. I mean on the click of more button, request to the server and after getting the contents, we can re-frame. what is wrong there??

Answer (score 0):

As Yusuf mentioned, it should be done at server side. Here are the base steps:

- In request send one param, **(int fromIndex)**, initially it will be 0, for next request it will be text length. So that service side, it requires to get substring which starts from the length value.
- In response send two params **(string subString, int fullLength)**. So now append your textview.text with subString.
- Now check,

> textView.text.length < fullLenght,

then display "Show More" button which will hit the service request again.

- Next time

> fromIndex = textView.text.length

This is the base logic. Apply this as per your service environment.

Hope this will help you.